# DFS implemtation on an Array of objects in Typescript/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I have a Class containing keys, values and children like this

```
class Container{
    key: string,
    value: string,
    children: Container[]
}

function searchKey(container: Container, key:string){
    if (container.key == key) {
        return container;
    }
    else if (container.children.length>0){
        for (let child of container.children) {
            let found = searchKey(child, key);
            if (found != null) {
                return found;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Input which I will be supplying to searchKey() function would be an array with deep objects and I want to get value for the supplied key parameter. But the current searchKey() function would not accept an array. How to make it to work with an array as input?

Comment: shouldn't it be function searchKey(container: Container[], key:string){

Comment: @marvel308 If i make container parameter as array, I cant call searchKey() function recursively

Comment: can't you make another function which accepts an array and calls this searchKey as a utility ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `searchKey()` function currently accepts a single `Container` and checks it for a match against `key`.  If it fails, it iterates through the `children` array of `Container`s and calls itself recursively on each one.

If you only intend to call the function with an *array* of `Container` and never need to pass in a single `Container`, then you can turn the function inside-out like this:

```
function searchKey(containers: Container[], key: string): Container | null {
  if (containers.length > 0) {
    for (let container of containers) {
      if (container.key == key) {
        return container;
      } else {
        let found = searchKey(container.children, key);
        if (found != null) {
          return found;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

(I tried to keep the above function in the same style as your original.)

This `searchKey()` function starts off by iterating through an array of `Container`s.  It checks each `Container` for a `key` match, and if it doesn't find it, it calls itself recursively on the `children` array.

---

There are other ways of doing this, of course.  Examples:

- two mutually recursive functions;
- a single dual-purpose function that accepts `Container | Container[]` arguments;
- a simple shim which calls your existing `searchKey()` with a dummy `Container` object whose `children` is the array you want.

Which one is best depends on your use case.

Hope that helps; good luck.